# Youtube API: Top Live Games

Tags: youtube-api

Which API call to use to get the list of "Top Live Games" on the youtube API?

**https://www.youtube.com/gaming/games** [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CORvU.jpg)

It seems to me that "Games" is a category, which can be found in the "youtube.videoCategories.list" call.

```
{
  "id": "20",
  "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ",
    "title": "Gaming",
    "assignable": true
  }
},
```

However, the call does not support child elements, just the snippet.
The individual "games" in there seem to be auto-generated channels.

However, when calling "youtube.channels.list" and setting "categoryId" to "20", I get:

```
{
   "domain": "youtube.channel",
   "reason": "categoryNotFound",
   "message": "Channel category not found.",
   "locationType": "parameter",
   "location": "categoryId"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `channel_id` of the [Gaming YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/gaming).

The `channel_id` of the [Gaming YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/gaming) is: **UCOpNcN46UbXVtpKMrmU4Abg**.

Unfortunately, I couldn't retrieve the live gaming videos by this way, so I have to check the [Live YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4R8DWoMoI7CAwX8_LjQHig).

Once I check the "Live: gaming" section, I can use its `playlistid` which is: **PLiCvVJzBupKkpGacV_ScUzA-eGF2KSZKC**.

This is the [playlist of the live gaming](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLiCvVJzBupKkpGacV_ScUzA-eGF2KSZKC) if you're interested in.

Once you have the `playlistid` of the "Live: gaming" section, use the for get *(let's say: the top 10 live games)*.

This is the YouTube Data API request you can use for retrieve top 10 live games:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&maxResults=10&playlistId=PLiCvVJzBupKkpGacV_ScUzA-eGF2KSZKC&fields=items(contentDetails%2FvideoId%2Cid%2Csnippet%2Ftitle)%2Ckind%2CnextPageToken%2CpageInfo%2CprevPageToken%2CtokenPagination&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

And the results vary from region - the following results are from Latin America:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
 "nextPageToken": "CAoQAA",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1000,
  "resultsPerPage": 10
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "id": "UExpQ3ZWSnpCdXBLa3BHYWNWX1NjVXpBLWVHRjJLU1pLQy4zM0M5OTA4RTE2OEVBMTEz",
   "snippet": {
    "title": "THE DARK INTERNET: ¡GAMEPLAY EXCLUSIVO DE LA PRÓXIMA ACTUALIZACIÓN 1.1.0! ⭐️ iTownGamePlay"
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "Jl8YMVQfFTw"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": "UExpQ3ZWSnpCdXBLa3BHYWNWX1NjVXpBLWVHRjJLU1pLQy44RDE1Q0NGQTIyNDVBMjYz",
   "snippet": {
    "title": " DIRECTO | NUEVO EZA DE VEGETA Y TRUNKS EN DOKKAN BATTLE"
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "k6MhzkxaNPw"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": "UExpQ3ZWSnpCdXBLa3BHYWNWX1NjVXpBLWVHRjJLU1pLQy5EQzdBMTk0QUNCMTFDODM4",
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Campeonato de Europa de Ajedrez (7) y Campeonato de Estados Unidos (5)"
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "JDuVoBfuS-I"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": "UExpQ3ZWSnpCdXBLa3BHYWNWX1NjVXpBLWVHRjJLU1pLQy4yOTNDM0Y1QjE3OUQ3NTVF",
   "snippet": {
    "title": "FREE FIRE *DE RUTA A LOS 3600* [EX TOP GLOBAL] //CAPITAN"
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "6fvjeB6jukM"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": "UExpQ3ZWSnpCdXBLa3BHYWNWX1NjVXpBLWVHRjJLU1pLQy4xQTI1REI0MTgyNkFFRjFD",
   "snippet": {
    "title": "YO INTERNETO EP.6: Me duelen los Mods"
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "m6rK02kD_io"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": "UExpQ3ZWSnpCdXBLa3BHYWNWX1NjVXpBLWVHRjJLU1pLQy43QjJGQjYxMEQwRjRGRkQ3",
   "snippet": {
    "title": "!!ÚLTIMO INTENTO EN DIRECTO¡¡ ¿CONSEGUIREMOS LAS 20 VICTORIAS CON ADRIÁN DE COACH? I  Clash Royale'"
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "ko2dzJh4E8I"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": "UExpQ3ZWSnpCdXBLa3BHYWNWX1NjVXpBLWVHRjJLU1pLQy5EM0I5QkM1RTQyNDk5RUI2",
   "snippet": {
    "title": "EL NUEVO BATTLE ROYALE  *BATTLEFIELD V FIRESTORM*"
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "yhEHPFp9J1w"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": "UExpQ3ZWSnpCdXBLa3BHYWNWX1NjVXpBLWVHRjJLU1pLQy5GNTk3QTg1RDZGNUZGNENF",
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Jugando Niveles de SUSCRIPTORES en Vivo! | Super Mario Maker"
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "-WnrFEzbnhs"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": "UExpQ3ZWSnpCdXBLa3BHYWNWX1NjVXpBLWVHRjJLU1pLQy5GOTYwNDNGRDJCMkQ1QkI2",
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Si me ganas *TE DOY CUENTA RANDOM de FORTNITE* GRATIS!! 1vs1 CONTRA SUSCRIPTORES en PATIO DE JUEGO"
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "d-uQ_ete2Ko"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": "UExpQ3ZWSnpCdXBLa3BHYWNWX1NjVXpBLWVHRjJLU1pLQy42QTJGODE2OEZDOTc4Rjcx",
   "snippet": {
    "title": " DIRECTO DE FREE FIRE  GANA DIAMANTES Y PREMIOS JUGANDO *TE RETO* | SALAS PRIVADAS"
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "izYgIFMBKKo"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

This is the [Google API Explorer demo](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list?part=snippet%252CcontentDetails&maxResults=10&playlistId=PLiCvVJzBupKkpGacV_ScUzA-eGF2KSZKC&fields=items(contentDetails%252FvideoId%252Cid%252Csnippet%252Ftitle)%252Ckind%252CnextPageToken%252CpageInfo%252CprevPageToken%252CtokenPagination&_h=10&) I prepared.

This is the [popular live gaming](https://www.youtube.com/gaming/live) if you're interested in.

Comment: Your solution returns the top videos of a specific playlist (PLiCvVJzBupKkpGacV_ScUzA-eGF2KSZKC).

My question however was how to get the actual top-list of (live) games (which are acutally playlist themselves). So a list of playlists rather than a list of videos.

I want to build the list as in the example-image of the question.

Comment: @OliH currently, this is possible only via web-scraping.